# Do not remove items from Firebase recycler adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Is it possible to have Firebase's recycler adapter not remove items from its model, and only add them? Or do I have to use the listview adapter to achieve this?

I'm using it for a messaging application whose database references change over time, but I'd like the client-side messages not to disappear when the recycler adapter's database reference changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` from FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-recyclerview), then it will always show a direct reflection of the underlying collection/query. There is built-in way to make it show data that is no longer in the database.

Luckily FirebaseUI is open-source. So you could take the adapter (and its underlying [`FirebaseArray` class](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java), which is the real workhorse) and modify it for your needs.